# How do I serve static admin files in Django 1.4?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django project that was started with Django 1.2.  Now I'm trying to run it under Django 1.4,  in a development environment, using the built-in webserver.  One thing I cannot get working is the static files for the admin interface.  In my django server's window, I see:

```
Django version 1.4, using settings 'settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[18/Jul/2012 11:38:04] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6452
[18/Jul/2012 11:38:05] "GET /admin/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4249
[18/Jul/2012 11:38:05] "GET /admin/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4264
```

I see that ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX has been deprecated, but I'm clearly missing the HOWTO that tells me what I have to do to get the admin pages working in development.

Comment: Instead of `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`, use `STATIC_URL` and place the admin files under `<STATIC_URL>/admin/`.
If `ADMIN_MEDIA` pointed to a completely different URL, then you probably want to set the `STATIC_URL` to that url.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running collectstatic to gather your static files?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic

Comment: do I have to do this to make the admin interface work with a development server?

Comment: You don't _have_ to, but it's an easy way to pull the static files into your template directory automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I finally started another project with "django-admin startproject", and started picking through the settings file.  I found that the new settings file had:

- added 'django.contrib.staticfiles' to INSTALLED_APPS
- added a few STATIC_ settings.  I copied these four:

  STATIC_ROOT = ''

  STATIC_URL = '/static/'

  STATICFILES_DIRS = ()

  STATICFILES_FINDERS = ()

And now things appear to be working.

Answer (score -1):

In django 1.4 you can use the static tag

```
{% load static %}

<a href="{% static 'img/foo.png' %}">
```

Comment: but this is the (django-supplied) admin interface.  I should not have to change it, IMHO.